# Mongoose save embedded child and update to other table

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema as below and the business logic is like this:
User add a new product category and multiple product(which will be tie to the new category they add into the embedded child), and it will save in the schema below. At the same time, the product category ref that has been added will be updated to user

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    productname: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    productprice: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0.00
    }
});

var ProductCategorySchema = new Schema({
    categoryname: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    categorytype: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    product: [ProductSchema],
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    productCategory: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectID,
        ref: 'ProductCategory'
    }]
});

mongoose.model('ProductCategory', ProductCategorySchema);
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find the `user` information by `name`, then assign the `_id` of this `user` to `product.user`, and save this `product`. After save this `product` successfully, push the `product._id` into `user.productCategory`. then save this `user` eventually. Sample codes as below.

```
//1. create new ProductCategory
var pc = new ProductCategorySchema({....});

//2. add products into productCategory
pc.product.push({productname: 'p1', productprice: 10});
pc.product.push({productname: 'p2', productprice: 11});

User.findOne({name: 'u1'}, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
       // error handling

    //3. assign user._id to pc, then save pc
    pc.user = user._id;
    pc.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
           // error handling

        //4. push pc._id into this user
        user.productCategory.push(pc._id);
        user.save(function(err) {
              // ....
        });
    });
});
```